# mysql Limit 2 vs two query performance

Tags: mysql

Example table:

```
id      name           alias_page         lang        content
1   nombre_pagina     nombre_pagina        es     spanish content
2   page_name         nombre_pagina        en     english content
3   pagina_2          pagina_2             es     spanish content
```

In the above table each page have a name in their native language and alias_page  only in one language (spanish here)

That return english page (id = 2) because match alias_page and lang

```
SELECT * FROM content
WHERE 
    (name = 'nombre_pagina' OR alias_page = 'nombre_pagina')
AND
    lang = 'en'
LIMIT 1;
```

But if the page not exist in the requested language (ex: `pagina_2` ) I need to retrieve it in another language (spanish default for automatic translation purposing)

My Solution 1 (result will be managed in PHP):

```
SELECT * FROM content
WHERE 
    (name = 'pagina_2' OR alias_page = 'pagina_2')
AND
    (lang = 'en' OR lang = 'es')
LIMIT 2;
```

My Solution2:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM content
WHERE 
    (name = 'pagina_2' OR alias_page = 'pagina_2')
AND
    (lang = 'en')
LIMIT 1;

 if(FOUND_ROWS() = 0) THEN
     SELECT FROM content
     WHERE 
        (name = 'pagina_2' OR alias_page = 'pagina_2')
     AND
        (lang = 'es')
     LIMIT 1;    
 END IF;
```

Which of the two is better ? 
Or another solution better than both ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your original query, slightly modified with an ordering which puts the desired language at the top of the result set.  Then, use `LIMIT` as you already were:

```
SELECT *
FROM content
WHERE 
    (name = 'nombre_pagina' OR alias_page = 'nombre_pagina')
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN lang = 'en' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
LIMIT 1;
```

If there were an English language version of the content, it would be returned by the above query, even if the same content existed in other languages.  If English were not available, but e.g. Spanish were, then this alternate content would be returned.